# Error The file 'Resources/LaunchScreen.xib' conflicts with 'Resources/LaunchScreen.xib'. ios xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, macos, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I am working with a `Xamarin` application where I have already built both `IOS` and `Android` applications. I am using `Visual Studio 2019` for the development and use `iPhoneSimulator` to test the application, after connecting to the mac device. Suddenly I am getting an error as preceding.

```
Error The file 'Resources/LaunchScreen.xib' conflicts with 'Resources/LaunchScreen.xib'.
```

Anyone ever faced this issue before, I am 100% sure that it is not related to any recent code changes, thus providing codes wouldn't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was sure that the issue is not related to the recent code changes. I did the preceding things first.

1. Clean the solution and rebuild
2. Delete the bin and obj folder manually and then rebuild

But I was getting the error again, the only thing which worked for me is **restarting the visual studio** and **open the project again**. Hope it helps.

Comment: If that doesn't solve, then try restarting your system. It may sound sarcastic, but trust me, its not.

Comment: This problem keeps happening to me. One other thing to try is do steps 1 and most of 2 then also go on the mac side and delete the ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/build/PROJECTNAME folder then rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error a lot, or various other errors that seem to be related with items being duplicated.  The easiest fix is to just disconnect from the Mac and reconnect.  This is assuming that you are developing on a PC and pairing to a Mac.  I suggested to the developers that they simply include disconnecting and reconnecting as part of the build process until they can figure out the actual cause.

If you are on the actual Mac, the process that Sibeesh Venu describes may be what occurs each time Xamarin pairs with the Mac.

The developers asked me, and others that have reported this issue, to turn on diagnostic debugging so that they can be provided with a log for when it happens.  I did this, and noticed that it occurs less frequently for me.  This makes me suspect that it's related to timing when files are processed.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6770#issuecomment-575310911

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue after after doing a merge in source control. It turns out that there was a duplicate instance of the .xib registration in my iOS.csproj file. In other words, there were duplicate lines that looked like this:

```
<InterfaceDefinition Include="Resources/LaunchScreen.xib.xib" />
```

Once I removed the duplicates, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: this resolved my issue on .NET MAUI. Thanks!